# Does every statement in begin end starts new transaction in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server, concurrency, transactions

For example, I have this code in my sql server procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test

Begin

Update table1
set col1 = 'a'

Update table2
set col2 = 15

select * from table3 

delete from table4
where col4 = 5;

end
```

When I exec test procedure, how many transactions I have?
Does begin end creates a new transaction? if not Will I have 4 implicit transactions?

Comment: Good question, but don't you also need a COMMIT ?

Comment: in this case, no. I did not create transaction I just opened block (begin end)

Answer (score 2):

`BEGIN` doesn't start a transaction no. `BEGIN TRANSACTION` does.

All `BEGIN...END` does on is own, really, is denote a code group. [BEGIN...END (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-end-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Encloses a series of Transact-SQL statements so that a group of Transact-SQL statements can be executed. BEGIN and END are control-of-flow language keywords.

If you want to have an explicit transaction, you need to use `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT`/`ROLLBACK`. I suggest having a look at [Transactions (Transact-sQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: So, in my stored procedure example, I will have no transaction when I execute it?

Comment: and what about implicit transactions if I in autocommit mode?

Comment: Everything is in a tranasction, @Jon . If you don't declare one, then all the statements will be in 1 implicit transaction, from the start of the batch, to the end.

Comment: I thought I will have 4 implicit transactions, so every statement will lock its table

Comment: No, there is one transaction. Locks and transactions are completely different things, @Jon . If the `DELETE` were to fail, then **everything** would be rolled back, not just the `DELETE`

Comment: Thank you, so we can say that with begin end we put everything in one transaction by default @Larnu?

Comment: `BEGIN...END` has *nothing* to do with transaction, @Jon ... As i said in my answer. Please take the time to ride the answer, and the cited documentation.

Comment: But HOW SQL server decides to put all of them into one transaction?

Comment: What do you mean "how"? You didn't define one, so it's all in one. *You* made that decision @Jon, not SQL Server. You were the one that wrote the SQL.

Comment: I mean I didn't create any transaction by myself. So, If I did not define explicitly any transaction SQL server puts all statements in the stored procedure in one transaction by default?

Comment: @Jon *"If you don't declare one, then all the statements will be in 1 implicit transaction, from the start of the batch, to the end."*

Comment: Thank you! @Larnu